# 8 cleaners clean an office block in 3 hours...

Tags: word-problem

I am stuck on this question style my teacher gives me each week. I have no idea to answer it and it hurts my brain! Please would you give some time to help me and walk me through this question:

- 8 cleaners can clean an office block in 3 hours. If the block needs to be cleaned in 2.5 hours, how many cleaners will be needed?

I've tried things like:

- 8 * 3 = 24

  24/2.5 = 9.6
- 8 / 3 = 2.66666667

  2.66666667 * 2.5 = 6.66666668
- [8/3 = N/2.5

  8*N = 3*2.5] I think I'm wrong here so I gave up this bit...

  and...

  went here:
- 8/3 = N/2.5

  8*2.5 = 3*N

  20 = 3N

  N = 20 / 3

I don't know where I'm at any more! Would any of you guys help me?

Much appreciated,

t.madx

Comment: It still takes 8 cleaners. Just tell them to work harder.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Haha! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it takes $3 * 8 = 24$ hours to clean the office. Ideally the work can be parallelized without loss, which I assume.

To clean the office in 2.5 hours time you'll need $24 / 2.5 = 9.6$ cleaners.
It will be hard to find a "0.6" cleaner. Hence you'll need 10.

In a real life situation this probably won't work.

Just think of washing the dishes. If 2 people can wash the dishes in 1 hour time, is it reasonable to assume that 10 people can do the same in 12 minutes? There will be such a crowd in front of the sink that it's likely they'll need even more than an hour.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated Ronald